# Assigning default values to properties of an object defined using interface in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am working on an Angular application, where I have defined some large custom form objects type using `interfaces` in Typescript. The property types are mostly `string`or `number`. 
I am using these object to fill a form using `ngModel` and therefore I need to assign default values to the properties of this object on the component side (otherwise, it gives error saying that object is `undefined`).
 
My question is what is a preferred or good way of assigning default values to the properties of these objects. I am aware of following ways:

- Use interface to define the shape of the object and assign a default value on  the component side (Currently, I am following this.)
- Use `Class` to define the object and assign a default value in the constructor. By this way, you don't have to worry about assigning default values on the component. I think this is a cleaner way of writing your component code. Not sure though as this is preferred way.

Let me know if using `class` is preferred a way to define complex objects (with nested properties) when using that object with `ngModel`. Also, if there are other ways to solve this issue.

Comment: `ngModel` does not require all inputs to have default values. Inputs can be left unfilled. So why do you feel you must have default values? Why not make the interface properties optional in the first place?

Comment: does your objects work without default values aside from filling form? for example, do they work in business logic terms? you didnt give too much details but since your main concern is filling the form it feels like you should set defaults on component side.

Comment: use `interface` (JSON object is not a function, hence doesnt match with a class technically...) and then `use a service` to get default instance of that interface (which would work like a constructor (don't do it in component, you will have to do it everytime)

Comment: @BeetleJuice Only If I make some properties optional in the interface..I can make some input unfilled and does not need to provide default values..is that correct?

Comment: right if the properties are optional, the compiler won't complain when they're missing

Answer (score 2):

I have a method like this in my service:

```
initializeProduct(): IProduct {
    return {
        id: 0,
        productName: null,
        productCode: null,
        tags: [''],
        releaseDate: null,
        price: null,
        description: null,
        starRating: null,
        imageUrl: null
    };
}
```